# visual studio 2010 using crystal reports and the results between 2 reports are not the same

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

In a VB.net 2010 desktop application that uses crystal reports, I am trying to compare the results of 2 reports where summary data should be the same between the 2 reports. When I run the same queries in access 2013, I get the same detailed results. However when I run the reports, the report called YTD sometimes has different total amounts. Thus I am trying to determine what could be causing the amount on the YTD report to change.

This report is not using formula fields, parameter fields, running total fields, special fields, unbound fields. There are 2 group name fields. The grand total amount in the report footer section does a sum on the MainData.Amount area. When I look at the database fields, the 'MainData' contains all the rows that the dataset select statement contains.

Thus could there be a selection of some data in the crystal report that I do not see? Thus can you tell me what I could try to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the Crystal Report, unhide or unsuppress all detail sections. Then add the field you are performing the Grand Total for into the detail section (if it is not already there). Then rerun the report.

This way, you will see every detailed record that Crystal is using to calculate the Grand Total. Perform your own manual addition of all detailed row values to verify if it adds up to the grand total in Crystal (no reason why it shouldn't)

This should give you the clues needed to determine if Crystal is including everything you want it to. If it is not, doublecheck your query and also the report filters screens.

Another piece of advice (if you aren't doing this already): when designing your report in crystal, if you've already written the query in MS Access, then you probably already know exactly which SQL you want, so when designing the report, use the same SQL statement as the datasource, as opposed to dragging tables in the report designer and drawing joins.

Comment: items: 1. you are saying to put a sum in the detail section like sum(purchase amount) or in a different area like group footer? 2. This is an existing report and the first time I am using crystal reports. 3. How do I 'doublecheck your query and also the report filters screens'? How can I find the query in the crystal report? The vb app does a datasource fill and I am assuming this supplied the data to crystal report. I have look at database expert and just see a reference is 1 table. 4. The vb app is only using 1 table to obtain the data from.